# Issues using rmate on remote servers to edit files using local Sublime Text editor

Tags: sublimetext3, remote-debugging, remote-server, sublime-text-plugin

I am trying to setup a workflow to use my local sublime text editor to edit remote files. I followed the steps found in these tutorials:

https://acarril.github.io/posts/ssh-sripts-st3

http://blog.keyrus.co.uk/editing_files_on_a_remote_server_using_sublime.html

https://stefanbauer.me/tips-and-tricks/edit-files-on-a-remote-server-via-ssh-with-sublime-right-in-your-terminal

I am using a ssh command: "ssh -R 52698:localhost:52698 -Y remoteHost", but when I run rmate on the remoteHost, I am getting these errors:

```
./rmate: socket: Address family not supported by protocol

./rmate: line 412: /dev/tcp/localhost/52698: Address family not supported by protocol

Unable to connect to TextMate on localhost:52698
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is your firewall blocking that port? Also, have you tried running `rmate` both with Sublime already open and with it not open?

Comment: Also, why are you using the `-Y` flag? You don't need X11 forwarding with `rmate`.

Comment: @MattDMo. Thanks for your help! I am using `-Y` because I am using other programs (MATLAB) that require X11 forwarding. I have tried using `rmate` both with and without my local Sublime Text open. In both cases, I got the same error as shown above. What would be an indication that firewall is blocking it? I tried to look for a firewall log but mine is empty!

Comment: After reading some more, I found that Sublime should be open before you try running `rmate`. At this point, the only thing I can suggest is to try opening your SSH session without `-Y` and see if that solves the problem. However, if it does, I'm not sure what to suggest next! Maybe open an issue in the `rmate` repo?